# Ext.js Ext.grid.Panel and filters

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this code ...

```
Ext.define("Requestor.view.main.RequestGrid", {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',     // Our base class. A grid panel.
... lots of code ...

  columns: [
... some more code ...

    {
      text: 'Status',
      dataIndex: 'status',
      renderer: function(value, metaData) {
        metaData.tdStyle = (value == 'Ready') ?
          'color:green;font-weight: bold' :
          'color:red;font-style: italic'
        return(value)
      },
      filter: { type: 'list', value: 'Ready' },
      flex: 1
     } 
... more code ...
```

This works great when the page initially loads, and if I manually, through the UI, change the filters to include other rows that do not have the value 'Ready' then appear. (see screen shot)

[image]

But if I try to change the sorting on my Status column the filter automatically changes back to just showing rows that have a status value of 'Ready'. (see screen shot)

[image]

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use filters of list type as follows->

```
                {
                    type: 'list',
                    dataIndex: 'indexName',
                    labelField: 'name',
                    store: Ext.create('MyStore')
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  BTW I have sench fiddle set up here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/s2e